# Automatically rename csv file via batch-file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I try to "automatically" rename a part of the name of my csv files (named
(e.g.) ´Trendreporting - 10.csv´ to ´Trendreporting.csv´) in a specific folder via batch file. 
To make it clearer, I want to change this:

```
Trendreporting - 10.csv ( the part behind the - is variable: (so e.g. also Trendreporting - 07.csv) but there´s always only 1 csv file in the folder at a time)
```

To this:

```
Trendreporting.csv
```

I tried it already with this query:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 for %%A in (TrendReporting - *.csv) do (
  set "name=%%A"
  ren TrendReporting - *.csv **
)
```

But nothing is happening when I execute the file - where´s the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
ren "TrendReporting - *.csv" "Trendreporting.csv"
```

The name containing the spaces must be enclosed in quotes, otherwise optional.

You don't need `delayedexpansion`, nor a `for`, nor do you need to pointlessly set `name`